# What does -2 do when using psftp.exe?

Tags: sftp, putty

I've just come across this line of code in a `.bat` file:

```
psftp -2 -l XXXXX 195.2.37.69 -pw XXXXX -P 10022 -b c:\sftp\sendfile.bat -v -bc -be
```

The help tells me what all the parameters do except for the `-2`.

Can anybody tell me what the `-2` does?

Comment: Have you tried `man psftp`?

Comment: just did - does not recognize it - but thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-2` or `-1` forces the use of a the corresponding SSH protocol version, so in your example it enforces the use of `SSH2`. You can also specify `-4` or `-6` which forces the use of respectively IPv4 or IPv6.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting the [`psftp` documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-sshprot):

> **3.8.3.16 -1 and -2: specify an SSH protocol version**
>
> The `-1` and `-2` options force PuTTY to use version 1 or version 2 of the
>   SSH protocol. These options are only meaningful if you are using SSH.
>
> These options are equivalent to selecting your preferred SSH protocol
>   version as ‘1 only’ or ‘2 only’ in the SSH panel of the PuTTY
>   configuration box (see [section 4.18.4](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-prot)).

So the `-2` forces SSH version 2.

In older versions, the `psftp` tried the SSH version 2 and fell back to the SSH version 1, if the server did not support the version 2. With `-2`, the fallback to an insecure version 1 did not happen and connection is abandoned. The latest versions do not fall back by default anymore. Nowadays, no serious SSH/SFTP server even supports the version 1 anyway.